# CSS class selector not applied when using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

So I have an application that just displays one single HTML page with some JS logic.

Now I want to create buttons from each entry in an array:

```
    let arrayButtons = [
        {
            title: "Apple",
            source: "http://www.cnn.com",
            icon: '\'./resources/Icon_Apple.png\'',
        },
        {
            title: "Raspberry",
            source: "http://www.cnn.com",
            icon: '\'./resources/Icon_Raspberry.png\'',
        },
        {
            title: "Kiwi",
            source: "http://www.cnn.com",
            icon: '\'./resources/Icon_Kiwi.png\'',
        }
    ]

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayButtons.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML +=
            "<div><button class='changeButton'><i class=\"icon\"></i>" + 
            arrayButtons[i].title + "</button></div>";
    }
```

As you can see, I try two versions to access the class selector: `class='changeButton'` as well as `class=\"icon\"`.

Here is the structure of the file as a whole:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        .changeButton {
            width: 90%;
            box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px black;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .changeButtonContainer {
            background-color: red;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .icon {
            //background: url('./resources/Icon_Apple.png') no-repeat; // dynamically adjust icon based on icon URL in the array
            width: 50px;
            height: 57px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div>
       <div id="buttons" class="changeButtonContainer"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>My Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>   
    window.onload = function () {
        displayButtons();
    };

    function displayButtons() {

        let arrayButtons = [
            {
                title: "Apple",
                source: "http://www.cnn.com",
                icon: '\'./dashboardresources/Icon_Apple.png\'',
            },
            {
                title: "Raspberry",
                source: "http://www.cnn.com",
                icon: '\'./dashboardresources/Icon_Raspberry.png\'',
            },
            {
                title: "Kiwi",
                source: "http://www.cnn.com",
                icon: '\'./dashboardresources/Icon_Kiwi.png\'',
            }
        ]

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayButtons.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML +=
                "<div><button class='changeButton'><i class=\"icon\"></i>" + arrayButtons[i].title + "</button></div>";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Do you know why the class selectors aren't applied? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: it actually does, as far as I see https://jsfiddle.net/yLwozvqc/

Comment: It works fine here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/oNjWmza and what do you still need??

Comment: Okay ... Really works in your fiddle/codepen! Now I wonder even more what's going on there o.O